# How to set matches in a list, set them to a variable, reformat output and pass it to another script?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, match

*Subheading:* "I'm here to learn."

I need to my several link collections from Markdown into another format (specifically, sending each line in a file to Evernote as a single note via [this script](http://nsuserview.kopischke.net/post/6223792409/i-can-has-some-markdown)).

My example files all look like this:

```
* [REF_1](URL)
* [REF_2](URL)
* [REF_3](URL)
```

**EDIT:** or to be more precise:

```
* [Koken Installtion Help](http://help.koken.me/customer/portal/articles/632102-installation)
* [A couple of Sass functions](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/12/sass-functions/)
* [Chris Coyier's Favorite CodePen Demos](http://davidwalsh.name/chris-coyiers-favorite-pens)
```

… and this is my battle plan:

1. Parse every line
2. Strip leading asterisks/hyphen/plus follwed by whitespace `^[\*\-\+]\s`
3. Match content of `[REF]` *(everything between square brackets)* with a regex `(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])` and set it to variable `${titel}`
4. Match content of `[URL]` *(everything between parenthesis)* with a regex `(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))` and set it to variable `${url}`
5. Format new output like in the example below.
6. Save to variable/clipboard/stdout (← I don't know which works best) and run `markdown2evernote.rb` on it
7. All lines are send? → Done.

**Example (see point 5):**

```
Notebook: ${notebook}
Title: ${title}
Url: ${url}
Keywords: ${keywords}

Content Area

Will use the $title and $url variable here again.
```

To be frank, I haven't come far. I'm already stuck at point two since I can't figure out how to get the regex to work. For now, my bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

document=~/file.txt
notebook="My test notebook"
keywords="test, demo"

cat ${document} | while read line; do \
    echo "$line" | sed -e '(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])'; \
done
```

I don't care if it's a sed/grep/awk solution – I take it all as long as it's a shell script.

I'd also be interested in what's the best way to proceed after having checked point 2 and 3 in the list and reach my goal of having a formatted output that I can hand over to the ruby script.

I have a vague idea as outlined above but it's quite a challenge since the scripts I've written so far where a lot simpler and didn't involve any of the above.

Comment: Is markdown really parsable with regexes? if not, you'll very soon have two problems: your original one, plus the regex problem.

Comment: You really mean `#!/bin/sh`, right? And better to explicitly call `#!/bin/bash` if that is what you really intend to use. calling just `sh` can lead to problems on different OSs. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Oh yes, that was a mistake. I prepared this question in my editor and uncommented all the lines… and the hash went, too. Double yes: I intended to use `#!/bin/bash`. Will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to extract the variables and write the output.

```
sed 's/^[*-+] *\[\(.*\)\](\(.*\))/Notebook: x\nTitle: \1\nUrl: \2\nKeywords: y\n\nContent Area\n\nWill use the \1 and \2 variable here again/' file.txt
```

By using `\(` and `\)` you can access the pattern inside these brackets with `\1`, `\2` and so on.

However, if your output consists of a lot of text, you'll blow up the `sed` command only with text, making it less readable. Data and program control structures should be separated, so I'd suggest something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fillText(){
    echo "Notebook: ${1}"
    echo "Title: ${2}"
    echo "Url: ${3}"
    echo "Keywords: ${4}"
    echo
    echo "Content Area"
    echo
    echo "Will use ${2} and ${3} variable here again."
}

document=file
notebook="My test notebook"
keywords="test, demo"

while read line; do
    title=$(sed 's/^[*-+] *\[\(.*\)\](.*)/\1/' <<< "${line}")
    url=$(sed 's/^[*-+] *\[.*\](\(.*\))/\1/' <<< "${line}")
    fillText "${notebook}" "${title}" "${url}" "${keywords}"
done < "${document}"
```

The function `fillText()` writes the output the way you'd like it, it takes four positional arguments, two of them are extracted from `"${document}"` with `sed`.

The fillText function could also be defined in a different file.

By the way, a comment on some part of your code:

```
cat ${document} | while read line; do \
    echo "$line" | sed -e '(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])'; \
done
```

is exactly the same as

```
sed '(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])' "${document}"
```

(disregarding that I don't know what `'(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])'` means.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate solution. The use of placeholder variables in the function is great. Didn't know about it. Unfortunately I didn't explain my needs exactly since I'm using real "Titles" and "URL's" instead of `[REF_1](URL)`. I outlined it all here <http://cl.ly/SFP7> – So the one thing that is missing - where I'm failing now - is the correct regex that matches the content correctly and works with a sed match pattern.

Comment: My bad. It should have worked from the first iteration on, but whitespaces (as usual!) were mixing things up. The `sed` command was fine, but passing the whitespaces as positional arguments to `fillText()` wasn't. I fixed that now. We use `sed` twice to get the different parameters and store it in a variable before passing it to  `fillText()`

Comment: Wow. That's a dream come true. The best part is that I now understand the sed regex better than before. I'll be capable of making varitions for other projects. That's great. Thanks a lot.